# Magento 2 - Catalog rules cronjob stuck at working with increased number of backlogs

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-2.2.5, indexing, catalog-rules

Catalog Rule Product, it always shows as working and and 735 in backlog

[image]

Tried these but didn't work for me:

- Reindexing
- Changed state to "Update on Save" then revert back to scheduled
- Wait for a day to reindex using magento cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following stuff:

First You need to change the mode of indexing to `Update on Save` by using this command

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime
```

After that you need to reset the indexing

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

After that truncate `_cl` tables related to your issue occuring indexing

After that reindex the indexing

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Finally you need to change the mode of indexing to `Update by Schedule`

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule
```

I hope it may help you in empty the backlog of indexing

Comment: Will surely try this. Thanks

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/321410/55041 is otherwise working for me, but truncating sets auto increment of the table back to 1. This causes backlog being processed only after auto increment reaches version id set in mview table. Therefore, in mview table, the version id needs to be reset (to zero) as well.