# Magento 2.4.6 P3 On-schedule price indexers stuck in "working" status

Tags: magento2.4.6

We recently updated the Magento version from 2.4.3 to 2.4.6 p3. After the upgrade, we are encountering an issue specifically with the price index. Manually, it works fine.

**When someone updates price data in bulk, or there is a price update using code, or any bulk product status changes using CSV import, the cron job is unable to finish the price index. It consistently shows a working status with backlog product items. However, if we run the indexer reset command from the console, the indexer starts working automatically using cron.**

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321405/magento-2-catalog-rules-cronjob-stuck-at-working-with-increased-number-of-back

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution of adding lock mode for reindex processes
you can enable use_application_lock mode for reindexing  by configuring the `app/etc/env.php` file

```
<?php
return [
    'indexer' => [
        'use_application_lock' => true
    ]
];
```

with the setting enabled, it uses the lock manager of magento, if the process crashes, the lock will be freed and magento will know that it can try to reindex the indexer again on the next cron execution

Also please check your "innodb_buffer_pool_size"  and may you need to increase
Below are the references for your issues you can check out for;

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36724 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5146

 https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/indexing/#using-application-lock-mode-for-reindex-processes

Comment: we have allready tried this but its not working